# Sum absolute difference in dataframe

Tags: r, forecasting

I have a small dataframe with values for 10 periods.  I want to sum the absolute difference (absolute error) between each value and the predicted value.

Column labels: P1, P2, P3, .....P10

Values: 3, 4, 3 ......7 (see data below)

Predicted value = 5 (it is not always 5)

"error" formula = |3-5|+|4-5|+|3-5|+....+|7-5|

```
> data
   cust P1 P2 P3 P4 P5 P6 P7 P8 P9 P10 predict error
1     A  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1       5     ?
2     B  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3   3       5     ?
3     C  1  1  1  1  1  3  3  3  3   3       5     ?
4     D  1  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  1   0       5     ?
5     E  1  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  0   1       5     ?
6     F  1  3  1  3  1  3  1  3  1   3       5     ?
7     G  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5   5       5     ?
8     H  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8   8       5     ?
9     I  5  5  5  5  5  8  8  8  8   8       5     ?
10    J  5  0  5  0  5  0  5  0  5   0       5     ?
11    K  5  0  0  5  0  0  5  0  0   5       5     ?
12    L  5  8  5  8  5  8  5  8  5   8       5     ?
```

I can do the calculations in a long format, but I don't want to redo long messy formulas for different size data.  The eventual dataset will have many more periods and customers, so I need a formula / function that will work for different sizes of data frames.  I would appreciate some help.

I know that this can be done using forecasting packages, but I need to build it from the bottom so that I can do other things with the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that a lot of the reason for your aversion to answers involving `melt`ing long are because of code like the other two answers that have appeared here. They do the job -- but are practically unreadable.

Using `dplyr` & `tidyr`, produces general as well as readable code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

# read data in
dfX = as_data_frame(read.table(textConnection("
                cust P1 P2 P3 P4 P5 P6 P7 P8 P9 P10 predict error
1     A  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1       5     ?
               2     B  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3   3       5     ?
               3     C  1  1  1  1  1  3  3  3  3   3       5     ?
               4     D  1  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  1   0       5     ?
               5     E  1  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  0   1       5     ?
               6     F  1  3  1  3  1  3  1  3  1   3       5     ?
               7     G  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5   5       5     ?
               8     H  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8   8       5     ?
               9     I  5  5  5  5  5  8  8  8  8   8       5     ?
               10    J  5  0  5  0  5  0  5  0  5   0       5     ?
               11    K  5  0  0  5  0  0  5  0  0   5       5     ?
               12    L  5  8  5  8  5  8  5  8  5   8       5     ?"),
                 header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))

# melt & compute error
dfXErr = dfX %>%
  select(-error) %>%                    
  gather(period, actual, -cust, -predict) %>%
  group_by(cust) %>%
  summarize(mape = mean(abs(actual - predict)))

# join back to original data (if required)
inner_join(dfX, dfXErr, by = "cust")
```

Comment: All the reply's work, thanks to everyone for the help!  I think dplyr is the way to go, it is easier to read.  I intend to become more familiar with it and use it more.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick

```
data$error <- rowSums(abs(data[,grepl("^P\\d+", names(data))] - data$predict))
```

It assumes all the periods start with a "P" followed by one or more digit.

Answer (score 0):

```
data$error <- apply(apply(data[,-c(1,12)], 2, function(x) abs(x - data[,12])),1, sum)
data
   cust P1 P2 P3 P4 P5 P6 P7 P8 P9 P10 predict error
1     A  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1       5    40
2     B  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3   3       5    20
3     C  1  1  1  1  1  3  3  3  3   3       5    30
4     D  1  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  1   0       5    45
5     E  1  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  0   1       5    46
6     F  1  3  1  3  1  3  1  3  1   3       5    30
7     G  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5   5       5     0
8     H  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8   8       5    30
9     I  5  5  5  5  5  8  8  8  8   8       5    15
10    J  5  0  5  0  5  0  5  0  5   0       5    25
11    K  5  0  0  5  0  0  5  0  0   5       5    30
12    L  5  8  5  8  5  8  5  8  5   8       5    15
```

Comment: Thanks.  This works, although I prefer to not call out specific locations (such as [,-c(1,12)]...) since this makes it awkward if I add periods.

Answer (score 0):

A solution using a for-loop (probably slower than the other solutions):

```
df = data.frame(P1=c(1,2,3),P2=c(4,5,6),predict=c(5,5,6))
numLabels = 2
df$error = 0
for(i in 1:numLabels) {
  df$error = df$error + abs(df[,paste0("P",i)] - df$predict)
}
```